# I got an error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')" when use vuepress to route to sidebar link page

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuepress

my project used to be running normally,but Recently，after I remove the `package-lock.file`, `rm -rf node_moduiles/` and run `npm i` again ,even though it's installed correctly,it's running with an error which looks like caused by different vue versions（2.6.11 ～ 2.7.8）.

```
vue.esm.js?a026:5059 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')"

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <Navbar> at node_modules/@vuepress/theme-default/components/Navbar.vue
         <Layout> at node_modules/@vuepress/theme-default/layouts/Layout.vue
           <GlobalLayout> at node_modules/@vuepress/core/lib/client/components/GlobalLayout.vue
             <Root>
warn$2 @ vue.esm.js?a026:5059
vue.esm.js?a026:3732 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
    at setCurrentInstance (vue.esm.js?a026:564:1)
    at callHook$1 (vue.esm.js?a026:3098:1)
    at Object.insert (vue.esm.js?a026:4877:1)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.esm.js?a026:6894:1)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.esm.js?a026:7105:1)
    at Vue._update (vue.esm.js?a026:2846:1)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.esm.js?a026:2947:1)
    at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js?a026:4119:1)
    at Watcher.run (vue.esm.js?a026:4195:1)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.esm.js?a026:3193:1)
logError @ vue.esm.js?a026:3732
vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:16 [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
warn @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:16
vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2316 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
    at setCurrentInstance (vue.esm.js?a026:564:1)
    at callHook$1 (vue.esm.js?a026:3109:1)
    at watcherOptions.onTrigger (vue.esm.js?a026:2959:1)
    at Dep.notify (vue.esm.js?a026:780:1)
    at Vue.reactiveSetter [as _route] (vue.esm.js?a026:1019:1)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:3003:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTML5History.eval [as cb] (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:3002:1)
    at HTML5History.updateRoute (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2414:1)
    at eval (vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2263:1)
```

Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Can you share your routing code ?

Comment: the routing code is from  ```node_modules/@vuepress/theme-default/components/Navbar.vue```,it's not in my own project, only the dependencies . and  it's running until I update the vue version to 2.7.8.

Comment: Are you getting any error while `npm install` ??

Comment: only the warning message is printed.I'm trying to refactor the code with the newest vue2 version. from the lock file,I can see vuepress install the dependencies  with "^" to maintain the major version 2, but others still the latest,and I'm trying to debug this error by single step to see waht happend.

Comment: I got an answer from https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12627 ,but I use the same method, it's not take effect.

Comment: Try deleting node_modules and try `npm install` and let me know the response on the terminal...

Comment: @Sujith Sandeep Thanks a lot for answering my question, https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12627,  is really solved my problem after I modify the source code.